# Integral multivariable equation on unit circle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have integral

$$\iint_D\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \,dx\,dy\,,$$

where $D$ is the unit circle's first quadrant

I've applied bounds to get

$$\int^1_0 \int^\sqrt{1-x^2}_0 f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$

Comment: Polar coordinates are the most appropriate.

Comment: My question says I'm not allowed to transform the domain - would using polar coordinates be doing that?

Comment: I would also do polar coordinates, but I agree that these instructions mean that you're not allowed to do that.  Fortunately, the integral can be done in rectangular coordinates fairly easily, as long as $x$ is on the inside.

Comment: Notice that if the integral ends $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$, then the bounds on the inner integral have to involve $y$, not $x$. So you can write either $\int_{y=0}^{y=1}\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt{1-y^2}}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ (easier in this case) or $\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$ (harder).

Comment: The title of your questions should ideally be informative. Stating the actual question in the title helps in getting more response besides helping in searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int^1_0 \int^\sqrt{1-y^2}_0 \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\,dy=\int^1_0 \left.\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right|_0^\sqrt{1-y^2}\,dy=\int^1_0 (1-y)\,dy$$

or in polar coordinates

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1\cos\theta\,r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta\,d\theta\int_0^1\,r\,dr.$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with the notation used in the middle equation on the first line, could you please explain what that means?

Comment: @gannicus37: just a definite integral.